# Check the lmgrd log file, or try lmreread - An error when loading an Open MPI program in Totalview

Tags: openmpi, totalview

When I load a program in TotalView, I am getting a warning dialog box "Check the lmgrd log file, or try lmreread" and the program doesn't load.

I am first selecting the correct Program from the Program tab, then I am selecting "Open MPI" from the Parallel tab and using four tasks.  When I click OK, the warning dialog appears and the debugger doesn't load.

I am using Totalview 8.9.2-2 and Open MPI 1.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a license error. Probably your license server isn't configured correctly.

We'd love to help you out with this. Give us a shout at tvsupport@roguewave.com or fill out a support request on our website at http://www.roguewave.com/support/contact-support/file-a-support-request.aspx

Cheers,
Chris Gottbrath

I'm the product manager for TotalView over at Rogue Wave Software